# PowerShell marks me errors with ")"

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a problem with this powershell snippet:

```
sc sdset bits D:(A;CI;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;SAFA;WDWO;;;BA)
```

It marks me a lot of errors with ")" in the characters 19, 54, 57, 90, 93, 112, 115, 134, 140, and 155. How can I fix it?

Comment: As "sc" is not a PowerShell CMDlet, I suggest to create a separate .bat file, put all needed CMD commands there and call this .bat from powershell script, it will help to avoid a lot of syntax problems and escaping

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev Actually, `sc` is an alias for `Set-Content` in PowerShell, so it kind of is a PowerShell cmdlet. That is not what the user is intending to use, but it *is* a cmdlet, or at least an alias for one.

Comment: Yet another annoyance with powershell aliases that mask an actual built-in exectuable in Windows. I don't get why they did that, more than once.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks for precision, my bad, of course I meant `sc.exe`

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use PowerShell to execute third party executables you need to remember that PowerShell will try to interpret the command and apply it's logic to things. If you don't want to it parse, and just want it to execute things you need to use the Stop Parsing command of `--%`. This should resolve your issue when executing that command in PowerShell (I also use the call operator `&` to tell PowerShell you're running an external application not a cmdlet, as well as specifying `sc.exe` instead of just `sc`):

```
& sc.exe --% sdset bits D:(A;CI;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;SAFA;WDWO;;;BA)
```

Comment: In general I'd favor specifying the executable entirely as `sc.exe`. That way it's clear to Powershell and future readers what you're intending.

Comment: @BaconBits Excellent point! I have updated my answer to reflect that.